# Configuring Automapper in N-Layer application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, automapper, n-tier-architecture

I have an N-Layer application as shown below

**MyApp.Model** - contains edmx and data models

**MyApp.DataAccess** - Repositories with EF

**MyApp.Domain** - Domain/business models

**MyApp.Services** - services(class library)

**MyApp.Api** - ASP.NET Web API

I am using Unity as my IoC container and **Automapper** for OO mapping.

My DataAccess layer references Model layer which contains all my Data objects.

I do not want to refer my model project in my Api layer. So returning DomainObjects (business models) from service layer and mapping to DTOs in API layer(DTOs are in API layer).

I configured domainModel to DTO mapping in API layer as below

```
public static class MapperConfig
{
    public static void Configure() {
        Mapper.Initialize(
            config => {
                config.CreateMap<StateModel, StateDto>();
                config.CreateMap<StateDto, StateModel>();

                //can't do this as I do not have reference for State which is in MyApp.Model
                //config.CreateMap<State, StateModel>();
                //config.CreateMap<StateModel, State>();
            });
    }
}
```

Now my question is how/where to configure my auto mapper mappings to convert my Entity models to Domain models?

To do in my API layer I do not have reference to my model project. I believe I should do this in service layer but not sure how to do that. Please help how to configure this mapping.

**Note:** Before asking here I googled with all eyes

1. [Where to place AutoMapper map registration in referenced dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136415/where-to-place-automapper-map-registration-in-referenced-dll)  says to use static constructor which I do not think a good option to add in all my models (I have 100 models) and another answer says to use PreApplicationStartMethod for which I have to add reference to System.web.dll to my services which is not correct.
2. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/automapper-users/TNgj9VHGjwg also did not answer my question properly.

Comment: "Entity models" → You only mentioned that once, how would we know?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#profile-instances

Comment: @aaron sry. "Entity models" are the classes in MyApp.Model project created by edmx generator.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu thanks for your link will give a try and get back to you.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu How does that help?

Comment: That page explains how you configure AM in an app that uses modules that need AM.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create mapping [profiles](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#profile-instances) in each of your layer projects, then tell AutoMapper to use those profiles in the topmost/outermost (invoking) layer that references all the lower layers. In your example:

> MyApp.Model

```
public class ModelMappingProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public ModelMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<StateModel, StateDto>();
        CreateMap<StateDto, StateModel>();
    }
}
```

> MyApp.Api

```
public class ApiMappingProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public ApiMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<State, StateModel>();
        CreateMap<StateModel, State>();
    }
}
```

> MyApp.Services

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => 
{
    cfg.AddProfile<MyApp.Model.ModelMappingProfile>();
    cfg.AddProfile<MyApp.Model.ApiMappingProfile>();
});
```

or if you are using a DI container (e.g. [SimpleInjector](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/)):

```
container.RegisterSingleton<IMapper>(() => new Mapper(new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
{
    cfg.AddProfile<MyApp.Model.ModelMappingProfile>();
    cfg.AddProfile<MyApp.Model.ApiMappingProfile>();
})));
```

Comment: And probing is built in now, so that would be the simplest way. Of course you can let the DI container do that.